# vb.net when progress bar executes no action should be done by end user

Tags: vb.net

When I run exe file in vb.net I execute a progress bar. When the progress bar is running no action should be done by end user. How can I acheive it?

Comment: Your question is far too vague.  Also, SO is specifically to help you with problems you've encountered when writing your code, not to prevent you encountering those issues by telling you how to write the code in the first place.  It's up to you to make the effort first and then post here if an when you encounter a specific issue.  If you have no code to post then you should not be posting.

Comment: I'm presuming this is a winforms application. Set the main form's .Enabled property to false. If that isn't the case then please provide some more detail on what kind of an app it is and what you're wishing to prevent the user from doing